# Using with and alongside simultaneously

Tags: prepositions

In the following sentence

[The rise of Mr. Modi **with Mr. Shah alongside**, and their combined role in the party’s outstanding electoral performances in recent years, have inspired commentaries that put them on a pedestal.](https://www.thehindu.com/opinion/editorial/organisation-men/article28067274.ece)

Why are **with** and **alongside** used together when they both mean the same thing. Isn't it redundant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"with Mr. Shah alongside" means "with Mr. Shah accompanying Mr. Modi", so this is not redundant.

Also, note that this is in Indian English, where I believe that "alongside" is more commonly used in such constructions. But this would have been perfectly acceptable in a US newspaper, and I think in a UK paper.

Answer (score 0):

The cited text is very precise in its intended meaning. When I first read it, I immediately thought that it would be far more "natural" to use a ***pre-positioned***<sup>1</sup> preposition / adverb...

> *The rise of Mr. Modi **alongside** Mr. Shah...*

...but although that particular sequence is far more common in general, the strong implication there would be that Shah was the ***primary*** "riser" (with Modi [*riding on Shah's coattails*](https://grammarist.com/idiom/ride-on-someones-coattails-and-coattail-effect/)). Conversely, the actual sequence used (***...with*** Mr. Shah **alongside**) implies that Shah's rise to prominence was a consequence of / assisted by ***Modi's*** rise.

(Idiomatically, the "lesser" *moves **alongside** / accompanies* the "greater", not the other way around.)

---

<sup>1</sup> Actually, it's not "pre-positioned" at all, regardless of where ***alongside*** is placed. In both cases it's "post-positioned" (comes *after* the noun it modifies). It's just a matter of which person's position is being defined relative to the other (where we naturally tend to define the less important thing / person relative to something better known).